# Integrate transformed norm over unit ball

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, analysis

With the n-dimensional unit ball denoted by $S_d$, and a diagonal matrix $D$ with positive diagonal entries, is there a way to find
\begin{equation}
\int_{S_d} ||Dv||^2 \text{ d}v \qquad ?
\end{equation}

Can I somehow transform it into an integral over the radius?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $v=\frac{Z}{\|Z\|}$ where $Z=(Z_1,\ldots,Z_n)\sim N(0,I_n).$ Your integral is $$E(\frac{d_1^2Z_1^2+\cdots+d_n^2Z_n^2}{\|Z\|^2})=\frac{1}{n}(d_1^2+\cdots+d_n^2).$$

Comment: Thank you very much, although I meant to integrate over the unit ball instead of the unit sphere. Nevertheless I can use your answer to do a double integral. If I had a spherical uniform distribution $U_n$ (for example the distribution of $\frac{Z}{||Z||}*R$ with $R\sim$Unif(0,1) independent to $Z$, is it corrrect to say: $\int_{B_n} ||Dv||^2 \text{ d}U_n = \int_0^1 r^{n-1} \mathbb{E}(||D\frac{r}{||Z||}Z||^2)\text{ d}r = \int_0^1 r^{n-1}\frac{r^2}{n} (d_1^2+\ldots+d_n^2)\text{ d}r$?

Comment: Usually $B_n$ is for the ball. I guess your notation $\frac{Z}{\|Z|}*R$ means  multiplication. By the way if $X$ is uniform in the ball, $R=\|X\|$ is not uniform in $[0,1]$ but with density $nr^{n-1}.$ Your last formula is almost correct, but you have to multiply it by th volume of the ball.